# Get picture form web site

Tags: vba, image, xmlhttprequest

Please help to give some hints for if i want to get a picture from a web site. Some code has been write but cannot get the right picture.

```
Sub get_pic()

With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://igtb.bochk.com/index_tc.html"
    Do While .busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do Until .readystate = 4
        DoEvents
        Sleep 2000
    Loop

    Set aaa = .document.all.tags("iframe")(1).contentwindow.document.all.tags("img")
    For j = 0 To aaa.Length - 1
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
            [a1] = aaa(j).href
            .Open "GET", aaa(j).href, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .Send
            strFilename = "C:\test.png"
            ByteToFile .responsebody, strFilename
        End With
        Exit For
    Next

End With

End Sub
Function ByteToFile(arrByte, strFilename)
    With CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        .Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write arrByte
        .SaveToFile strFilename, 2 'adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

i know that will be change when you open any new request but is that any way to get the original picture when you open that page?

Comment: which picture? The pic at the top looks like it changes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.